# R Complex Association Plots

Tags: r, plot, categories

I'm not used to plotting with R, so bear with me.

I have three categorical independent variables-- price before, price after, and volume band-- and one categorical dependent variable.

I want to plot an association plot for counts of each factor in the dependent variable across the combinations of the three dependent ones.

Can someone point me to any resources that explain how to do this better than the vcd package documentation? Or give me a hint how to begin?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `spineplot` for two categorical variables; not sure for more than two

Comment: Hmm... I'm sure there's a way.

Comment: How about a `barplot()` where the total of each bar is the count number for each independent variable but the bar is split showing the number of counts associated with the dependent variable. Would you like an example with code?